# Menu link to block or div

Tags: routes, blocks

Is it possibile to link menu links to the div or block on the certain subpage? If yes what is the method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing that using the **#id** of that block or div in the path of menu link pointing to the page like below:

```
PAGE-PATH-URL/#ID-OF-BLOCK-OR-MENU
```

basically you can link the menu to any div, block or anything having **id attribute** by appending the **#ID** at the last of the page path.

Answer (score 1):

This is not *completely* straight forward. If you try to create and save a menu link like book/page#anchor-id, Drupal will give this error

> The path 'book/page' is either invalid or you do not have access
>   to it.

You will need the node ID. Drupal wants the link to look like this: node/55#block-you-want.

The easiest way to do this is

1. Save the menu link without the anchor id. ex: /book/page
2. Drupal will create the menu link like this: node/55
3. Edit your menu link to: node/55#anchor-id. Save again.